# JTessBoxEditor won't start on Ubuntu 16.04 (OpenJDK 8 or 9)

Tags: ubuntu, tesseract, java

having troubles running jTessBoxEditor 1.7.3 in Ubuntu 16.04 64Bit.

installed openjdk-9-jdk, got this message:

```
    $ java -jar jTessBoxEditor.jar
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f1b76d03009, pid=3964, tid=3988
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %P" (or dumping to /pool0/Xtreme/home/leo128/Scrivania/jTessBoxEditor/core.3964)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /pool0/Xtreme/home/leo128/Scrivania/jTessBoxEditor/hs_err_pid3964.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Annullato (core dump creato)
```

I took a minute to shorten the above mentioned log file. if you think I shortened it too much, I'll be glad to post the entire thing
Here is the shortened version:

```
    #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f1b76d03009, pid=3964, tid=3988
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %P" (or dumping to /pool0/Xtreme/home/leo128/Scrivania/jTessBoxEditor/core.3964)
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: jTessBoxEditor.jar

Host: Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5700  @ 3.00GHz, 2 cores, 1G, Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Time: Mon Sep 11 10:24:19 2017 CEST elapsed time: 1 seconds (0d 0h 0m 1s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f1b7035a800):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=3988, stack(0x00007f1b18153000,0x00007f1b18254000)]

Stack: [0x00007f1b18153000,0x00007f1b18254000],  sp=0x00007f1b1824e9d0,  free space=1006k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
C  [libfontmanager.so+0x33f8e]
C  [libfreetype.so.6+0x14d2b]  FT_Stream_Seek+0x1b

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler.initNativeScaler(Lsun/font/Font2D;IIZI)J+0 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler.<init>(Lsun/font/Font2D;IZI)V+26 java.desktop@9-internal
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0 java.base@9-internal
j  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+85 java.base@9-internal
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+5 java.base@9-internal
j  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+65 java.base@9-internal
j  sun.font.FontScaler.getScaler(Lsun/font/Font2D;IZI)Lsun/font/FontScaler;+39 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.TrueTypeFont.getScaler()Lsun/font/FontScaler;+21 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.FileFontStrike.<init>(Lsun/font/FileFont;Lsun/font/FontStrikeDesc;)V+204 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.FileFont.createStrike(Lsun/font/FontStrikeDesc;)Lsun/font/FontStrike;+18 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.Font2D.getStrike(Lsun/font/FontStrikeDesc;Z)Lsun/font/FontStrike;+92 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.Font2D.getStrike(Lsun/font/FontStrikeDesc;)Lsun/font/FontStrike;+3 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.CompositeStrike.getStrikeForSlot(I)Lsun/font/PhysicalStrike;+23 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.CompositeStrike.getFontMetrics()Lsun/font/StrikeMetrics;+31 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.initMatrixAndMetrics()V+28 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.<init>(Ljava/awt/Font;Ljava/awt/font/FontRenderContext;)V+62 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(Ljava/awt/Font;Ljava/awt/font/FontRenderContext;)Lsun/font/FontDesignMetrics;+128 java.desktop@9-internal
j  sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljava/awt/Font;)Ljava/awt/FontMetrics;+15 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(Ljava/awt/Font;)Ljava/awt/FontMetrics;+2 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthGraphicsUtils.getPreferredSize(Ljavax/swing/plaf/synth/SynthContext;Ljava/awt/Font;Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/swing/Icon;IIIIII)Ljava/awt/Dimension;+110 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLabelUI.getPreferredSize(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;)Ljava/awt/Dimension;+82 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+26 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.updateLayoutState()V+162 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.maybeUpdateLayoutState()V+8 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.valueChanged(Ljavax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent;)V+4 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(IIZ)V+64 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(II)V+7 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged()V+70 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(IIIIZ)V+92 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(IIII)V+7 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setSelectionInterval(II)V+59 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.JList.setSelectedIndex(I)V+20 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup.setListSelection(I)V+20 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup.access$300(Ljavax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicComboPopup;I)V+2 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.itemStateChanged(Ljava/awt/event/ItemEvent;)V+24 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(Ljava/awt/event/ItemEvent;)V+34 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged()V+64 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(Ljavax/swing/event/ListDataEvent;)V+28 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(Ljava/lang/Object;II)V+64 java.desktop@9-internal
j  com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKFileChooserUI$FilterComboBoxModel.propertyChange(Ljava/beans/PropertyChangeEvent;)V+42 java.desktop@9-internal
J 826 C1  java.desktop@9-internal9-internal (39 bytes) @ 0x00007f1b5a348aec [0x00007f1b5a3489a0+0x000000000000014c]
J 841 C1  java.desktop@9-internal9-internal (81 bytes) @ 0x00007f1b5a3568bc [0x00007f1b5a355c60+0x0000000000000c5c]
J 788 C1  java.desktop@9-internal9-internal (59 bytes) @ 0x00007f1b5a3397b4 [0x00007f1b5a338f20+0x0000000000000894]
j  javax.swing.JFileChooser.setFileFilter(Ljavax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter;)V+171 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.JFileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(Ljavax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter;)V+59 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.JFileChooser.updateUI()V+55 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.JFileChooser.setup(Ljavax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView;)V+22 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(Ljava/io/File;Ljavax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView;)V+123 java.desktop@9-internal
j  javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>()V+9 java.desktop@9-internal
j  net.sourceforge.tessboxeditor.Gui.initComponents()V+5
j  net.sourceforge.tessboxeditor.Gui.<init>()V+102
j  net.sourceforge.tessboxeditor.GuiWithMRU.<init>()V+1
j  net.sourceforge.tessboxeditor.GuiWithEdit.<init>()V+1
j  net.sourceforge.tessboxeditor.GuiWithSpinner.<init>()V+1
j  net.sourceforge.tessboxeditor.GuiWithFont.<init>()V+1
j  net.sourceforge.tessboxeditor.GuiWithLaF.<init>()V+1
j  net.sourceforge.tessboxeditor.GuiWithTools.<init>()V+1
j  net.sourceforge.tessboxeditor.GuiWithGenerator.<init>()V+1
j  net.sourceforge.tessboxeditor.GuiWithTrainer.<init>()V+1
j  net.sourceforge.tessboxeditor.GuiWithValidator.<init>()V+1
j  net.sourceforge.tessboxeditor.GuiWithValidator$1.run()V+4
j  java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch()V+47 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+21 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Ljava/awt/EventQueue;Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+3 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+32 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1 java.desktop@9-internal
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0 java.base@9-internal
j  java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+18 java.base@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+46 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)V+183 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+35 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3 java.desktop@9-internal
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9 java.desktop@9-internal
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000000

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000010002 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f1b1824e9d0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f1b7035a800
RBP=0x00007f1b1824e9e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f1b7035a800
RSI=0x0000000000010002 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000000000001db is an unknown value
R11=0x00007f1b76d02ff0: JNU_GetEnv+0x0000000000000000 in /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/libjava.so at 0x00007f1b76ce6000
R12=0x00007f1b3c27c490 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x00007f1b3c27c4f0 is an unknown value

...............................
...............................
...............................


Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0,482 Thread 0x00007f1b70011000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': sun/awt/resources/awtProvider> (0x00000000e332c350) thrown at [/build/openjdk-9-argm_o/openjdk-9-9~b114/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/systemDictionary.cpp, line 224]
Event: 0,504 Thread 0x00007f1b70011000 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000e334da08) thrown at [/build/openjdk-9-argm_o/openjdk-9-9~b114/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 605]
Event: 0,505 Thread 0x00007f1b70011000 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000e3356040) thrown at [/build/openjdk-9-argm_o/openjdk-9-9~b114/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 605]
Event: 0,740 Thread 0x00007f1b7035a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': com/sun/swing/internal/plaf/metal/resources/metalProvider> (0x00000000e31fc238) thrown at [/build/openjdk-9-argm_o/openjdk-9-9~b114/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/systemDictionary.cpp, line 224]
Event: 0,742 Thread 0x00007f1b7035a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': com/sun/swing/internal/plaf/basic/resources/basicProvider> (0x00000000e2f007a8) thrown at [/build/openjdk-9-argm_o/openjdk-9-9~b114/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/systemDictionary.cpp, line 224]
Event: 0,759 Thread 0x00007f1b7035a800 Implicit null exception at 0x00007f1b61722838 to 0x00007f1b617228c6
Event: 0,818 Thread 0x00007f1b7035a800 Implicit null exception at 0x00007f1b6172250f to 0x00007f1b61722579
Event: 1,146 Thread 0x00007f1b7035a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': com/sun/java/swing/plaf/gtk/resources/gtkProvider> (0x00000000e2c8a9a0) thrown at [/build/openjdk-9-argm_o/openjdk-9-9~b114/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/systemDictionary.cpp, line 224]
Event: 1,148 Thread 0x00007f1b7035a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': com/sun/swing/internal/plaf/synth/resources/synthProvider> (0x00000000e2c8ff70) thrown at [/build/openjdk-9-argm_o/openjdk-9-9~b114/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/systemDictionary.cpp, line 224]
Event: 1,149 Thread 0x00007f1b7035a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': com/sun/swing/internal/plaf/basic/resources/basicProvider> (0x00000000e2c93258) thrown at [/build/openjdk-9-argm_o/openjdk-9-9~b114/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/systemDictionary.cpp, line 224]

Events (10 events):
Event: 1,375 loading class sun/font/StrikeCache$SoftDisposerRef
Event: 1,375 loading class sun/font/StrikeCache$DisposableStrike
Event: 1,375 loading class sun/font/StrikeCache$DisposableStrike done
Event: 1,375 loading class sun/font/StrikeCache$SoftDisposerRef done
Event: 1,375 loading class sun/font/FileFontStrike
Event: 1,376 loading class sun/font/FileFontStrike done
Event: 1,376 loading class sun/font/FontScaler
Event: 1,376 loading class sun/font/FontScaler done
Event: 1,376 loading class sun/font/FreetypeFontScaler
Event: 1,377 loading class sun/font/FreetypeFontScaler done


Dynamic libraries:
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 264899                             /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:01 264899                             /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 264899                             /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
0123d000-0125e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
e1400000-e3400000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3400000-100000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
100000000-100220000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
100220000-140000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b0e428000-7f1b0e4e8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b0e4e8000-7f1b0e628000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b0e628000-7f1b0e62c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b0e62c000-7f1b0e729000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b0e729000-7f1b0e72a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b0e72a000-7f1b0ef2a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b0ef2a000-7f1b0ef2b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b0ef2b000-7f1b0f72b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b0f72b000-7f1b0f791000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 273141                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libibus-1.0.so.5.0.511
7f1b0f791000-7f1b0f990000 ---p 00066000 08:01 273141                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libibus-1.0.so.5.0.511
7f1b0f990000-7f1b0f992000 r--p 00065000 08:01 273141                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libibus-1.0.so.5.0.511
7f1b0f992000-7f1b0f993000 rw-p 00067000 08:01 273141                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libibus-1.0.so.5.0.511
7f1b0f993000-7f1b0f994000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1b0f9af000-7f1b0f9b5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 524569                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so
7f1b0f9b5000-7f1b0fbb5000 ---p 00006000 08:01 524569                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so
7f1b0fbb5000-7f1b0fbb6000 r--p 00006000 08:01 524569                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so
7f1b0fbb6000-7f1b0fbb7000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 524569                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so
7f1b0fbb7000-7f1b0fc0b000 r--p 00000000 08:01 918616                     /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
7f1b0fc0b000-7f1b0fc62000 r--p 00000000 08:01 918748                     /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-R.ttf
7f1b0fc62000-7f1b0fc7a000 r--s 00000000 08:01 918786                     /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/c059033l.pfb
7f1b0fc7a000-7f1b0fc94000 r--s 00000000 08:01 918780                     /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/c059013l.pfb
.......................................
.......................................
.......................................
.......................................

7f1b79b8d000-7f1b79b8e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffde0a59000-7ffde0a7a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffde0b39000-7ffde0b3b000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffde0b3b000-7ffde0b3d000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

VM Arguments:
java_command: jTessBoxEditor.jar
java_class_path (initial): jTessBoxEditor.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/home/leo128/bin:/home/leo128/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0xc12c20], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0xc12c20], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0xc12c20], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGPIPE: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=00000000000010000000000000000000, sa_flags=SA_RESTART
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0xa3b600], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0xc12c20], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0xa3b4a0], sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0xa3b870], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0xa3b870], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0xa3b870], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0xa3b870], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
uname:Linux 4.10.0-33-generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 14:07:24 UTC 2017 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.23 NPTL 2.23 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 7681, NOFILE 1048576, AS infinity
load average:0,77 1,08 0,56

.......................................
.......................................


CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, tsc

CPU Model and flags from /proc/cpuinfo:
model name  : Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5700  @ 3.00GHz
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm xsave lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority dtherm

Memory: 4k page, physical 2010896k(74736k free), swap 1952764k(1948008k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src) for linux-amd64 JRE (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src), built on Apr 14 2016 20:05:37 by "buildd" with gcc 5.3.1 20160413

END.
```

I hope it will be of any use.

Even if nobody knows how to solve this, I would appreciate a pointer to a fallback-solution, maybe in a comment as an indication, pointing me to another tesseract 3.04 compatible box-file editor that runs well in Ubuntu 16.04, possibly without lots and lots of headaches building it. Training Tesseract seems to be a real PITA, you know... I tried QT-Box-Editor but I had problems there too, will give it another chance if somebody had got it working on 16.04.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try with Oracle JDK/JRE 8.

Comment: yea man! that simple! you should have replied so I could accept it as valid. I am waiting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try launching it with Oracle JDK/JRE 8.